# Kerberos authentication

Tags: authentication, kerberos

i have a login form, i made a java client...i need to authenticate throw this login form with ticket.I did a controller and a javascript page with the ajax call, but I had to pass user and password to the call, when I started the application he looks at whether this user exists on my server and authenticates it ... my problem is that I do not  want to pass user and password for the call but I want it to be authenticated with a ticket. I looked a bit around but I have unclear ideas about this passage, maybe give me a little more detailed guidance. Thank you I saw that most people use LDAP, is better o can i do another road?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LDAP, you can pass it off as Basic in your code.

Read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication

However, if you're using Kerberos and Java, you can try using the SPNEGO library.